# why does fill method not work properly if applied on the same array multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

When I am doing this --

```js
var Array = [45, 87, 32, 86, 67, 23, 53, 69];
console.log(Array.fill("h", 1, 6));
console.log(Array.fill("h", 3));
```

then the output for the 2nd console.log always changes only the first index. But, when I comment out the first console line, then that one prints the true change in the array.

Comment: `.fill` mutates the array every time.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you please elaborate a little? It would be very helpful.

Comment: `a = [1, 1, 1]; a.fill(2); a.fill(3)` will make `a` (and all references to it) equal to `[3, 3, 3]`. Calling `.fill()` *doesn't* clone the array.

Comment: also do not declare a variable called `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Daniel. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: @HimanshuKumar the global array constructor is also called `Array`, so your declaration would shadow it. If you then try to use something like [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) you wouldn't be able to reach it.

Answer (score 4):

After you do :

```
console.log(Array.fill("h", 1, 6));
```

The Array becomes:

```
[45, "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", 53, 69]
```

So the array you had initially changes.

After this when you do:

```
console.log(Array.fill("h",3));
```

all the indexes starting from 3 become "h"